Matrix in PBI Sort by Total Values

I have this matrix table in PBI. Is there anyway that I can sort the ID #s (the column headers) based on values? The one with highest total should be the in the first column.
Current sorting options in PBI are not doing this.

Can you please check this tutorial - https://community.fabric.microsoft.com/t5/Desktop/Sort-Matrix-by-column-total-and-row-totals/td-p/340923
